# How to change the icon in ListView on click?

Tags: android, cursor, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

My `ListView` is linked to the database (with `SimpleCursorAdapter`).

What should I do once user clicked on the row to change the icon?
I've tried to:

1. update database value;
2. change icon manually;
3. call
   `myCursor.notifyDataSetChanged();`

It doesn't work - nothing is changed.
If I don't call `myCursor.notifyDataSetChanged();`, then icon is changed. But once I move ListView, it disappears. 
If I associate `myCursor` with `ListView` again, then it works, but the whole `ListView` is re-drawn, list is scrolled to the top, which is incorrect behaviour.

What should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you need to create a new cursor (so that the data is refreshed), and then set that new cursor into the `ListView`'s adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found the answer - I should `requery` the cursor.